# Do not want to write the value to the database

Tags: php, mysql

There is a script which pings all the ip addresses in the column "ip_address", I need to ping after reports he wrote in the column "status". I.e. If the computer is online, in the column "status" write the value 1, if the offline database set to 0. Example:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BTiAT.jpg]

He does not want to write this value. Here's my script:

```
<?php
include('db.php');
foreach($test as $value){
    exec("ping -c 4 " . $value->ip_address, $output, $result);
    if ($result == 0) {
        $insert_sql = "INSERT INTO test ('status')VALUES('1');";
     }else{ 
    $insert_sql = "INSERT INTO test ('status')VALUES('0');";
}
    echo "<br/>" . $insert_sql;
    }
?>
```

This is what happens :

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6vfyu.png]

**UPD:**

```
<?php
include('db.php');
foreach($test as $value){
    exec("ping -c 4 " . $value->ip_address, $output, $result);
    if ($result == 0) {
        $insert_sql = "update test set status='1' where ip_addres = '".$value->ip_address."'";
        mysqli_query($insert_sql);
     }else{ 
        $insert_sql = "update test set status='0' where ip_addres = '".$value->ip_address."'";
        mysqli_query($insert_sql);
}
    }
?>
```

That's right?

Comment: You have to use update not insert into.

Comment: Can you write how? PLS

Comment: 'Status' is a string. `status` is a column identifier

Answer (score 0):

You have to use update syntax:

```
<?php
include('db.php');
foreach($test as $value){
    exec("ping -c 4 " . $value->ip_address, $output, $result);
    if ($result == 0) {
        $insert_sql = "update test set status='1' where ip_addres = '".$value->ip_address."'";
     }else{ 
        $insert_sql = "update test set status='0' where ip_addres = '".$value->ip_address."'";
}
    echo "<br/>" . $insert_sql;
    }
?>
```

And do not use single qoutes around column names. single quotes are only for character values. if you have to escape column names you have to use backticks.

Comment: Thank you, but he does not write into the base :(
I don't know why

Comment: @TriSTaR you only print the statement . you never execute it.

Comment: it is never possible to write to the database?
I'm still a newbie this area

Comment: ... And prepared statements

Comment: @Jens, `$insert_sql = mysqli_query($load,"update test set status='1' where ip_addres = '".$value->ip_address."'");`
Is it true? Please sir, if you can help me...

Answer (score 0):

You need to:

- Initalize a **connection to your mysql database**, using and address, username and password (in your case to netmap.inp.uz). Just as you do in HeidiSQL. Maybe this is done in your db.php file. If it is not, see http://php.net/manual/es/function.mysqli-connect.php
- Instead of (or apart from) echoing your query, you must msqli_query($insert_sql), that is, have it **executed** by the database.

Right now, you are only sending the statement to the output.

Comment: I added mysqli_query($insert_sql) and it gives this error:
_Message: mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given_

Comment: Read the documentation: http://php.net/manual/de/mysqli.query.php . You have to add the db connection as first parameter

Answer (score 0):

This is a sample working code of your issue try this :

```
$test = array('www.google.com','msn.com','yahoo.com','stackoverflow.com','bhokat.com');

var_dump($test);
foreach ($test as $key => $value) {
    exec("ping -n 1 $value",$output[],$retval);
    if (strlen($output[$key][0]) > 0) {
        $sql = "UPDATE test SET status='1' WHERE ip_address=$value";
    } else {
        $sql = "UPDATE test SET status='1' WHERE ip_address=$value";
    }

    echo "<br/>" ;
}
```

Change update query as per your need. You need to update the field if already exist else insert, you can add extra check inside if and else part.